# Find unknown formatted date in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm currently struggling with a problem: I'm trying to find an (unknown formatted) date inside an given string. I've implemented a solution for german dates (`dd.mm.yyyy`) so far:

```
if(preg_match('/\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}/',$stringWithDateSomewhere, $date)) {
  $result['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date[0]));
}
```

I could continue adding several reg expressions trying to match the most common. Problem is: there are too many possible formattings to check for since it does not only has to check for german dates.

Is there a PHP class or function to find a date inside a string e.g. like the iPhone does with e-mails and websites?

An example for `$stringWithDateSomewhere`:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacus elit, 
dictum quis justo sit amet, sollicitudin malesuada velit. Nunc eget 
tempus ipsum. *19.10.2013* Morbi bibendum vitae lorem non euismod. In 
hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur *2nd February 2011* vitae pellentesque dui,mi.
```

Comment: you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), it does a pretty good job of guessing

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I first have to extract the substring containg the date before normalzing with `strtotime`.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe `/\d{2,4}.[\.-\/].\d{2}.[\.-\/].\d{2,4}/`

Comment: nevermind the d F Y breaks that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

This expression would capture two formats you have in your sample text. This doesn't check a string to ensure it's a valid date.

- match a format like `31.43.2013` where the two delimiters are not letters or numbers and are identical
- match a format like `2nd February 2011` where there is a digit, a month and a 4 digit string

`\d{1,4}([^a-z0-9])\d{1,4}\1\d{1,4}|\d(st|nd|rd|th)?\s?(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\b\s?\d{4}`

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

**Input Text**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacus elit, 
dictum quis justo sit amet, sollicitudin malesuada velit. Nunc eget 
tempus ipsum. *19.10.2013* Morbi bibendum vitae lorem non euismod. In 
hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur *2nd February 2011* vitae pellentesque dui,mi.
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/\d{1,4}([^a-z0-9])\d{1,4}\1\d{1,4}|\d(?:st|nd|rd|th)?\s?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\b\s?\d{4}/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19.10.2013
            [1] => 2nd February 2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

## Disclaimer

There are a ton of edge cases which this expression won't find. When discovered this expression can be updated to match the additional formats.

The expression may also capture things which are not actually dates, this is normal.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer & explanation! I've slightly modified the expression to match `10. June 2013`and `10 June 2013`:
`'/\d{1,4}([^a-z0-9])\d{1,4}\1\d{1,4}|\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th|.)?\s?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\b\s?\d{4}/im'`

Seems to match quite a lot formattings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as you are planning to detect dates in text, regular expressions are the answer. You'll have to manually add expressions to detect dates in various formats. `new DateTime($date)` works really well, but you need to feed it with text that you already know to be a date.

Comment: _"but you need to feed it with text that you already know to be a date"_ LOL, that's exactly what the question is...